# How to detect star sign "*" in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is my code..

```
/(?!\*)/.test("test*test")
```

The result still return true.

I want to validate the string which will return false if any * in string.

Something is wrong with code?

Comment: You can negate the `test` result with just `/\*/`

Comment: You can negate the output: `!(/\*/.test(str))`

Answer (score 4):

Your regex returns true because it matches the starting position. The test you have just says "is there a position that is not followed by a `*`?" which literally any string will match - even `"*"` matches because after the `*` there is a position that is not followed by a(nother) `*`.

If you want to test if a string does not contain a `*`, the simplest solution is:

```
"test*test".indexOf("*") < 0 // true if no * in string
```

Doing so with regex would be something like:

```
/^[^*]*$/.test("test*test")
```

But that's more work.

Comment: Thanks so much.All my brain was to think about regex and totally forget indexOf ...XD

Comment: It happens to all of us at some point, I'm sure :D Regex is a powerful tool, but sometimes it's too powerful for the task at hand. Kinda like jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Simply test for presence of `*` and negate the output

```
var string="123*456";
console.log(  !(/\*/.test(string))  );
false

var string="12*34*56";
console.log(  !(/\*/.test(string))  );
false

var string="123456";
console.log(  !(/\*/.test(string))  );
true
```